# How to render in promise's resolve

Tags: javascript, reactjs, promise

Because I need to access indexeddb in the react's render, I use promise and separate the logics in the render.

```
render(){
  if(original_flow) dispatch(applyUserAccFilters(groups));
  //access indexeddb
  else applyShopNameFilters(window,groups).then((
       ()=>{groupListItems=[];groupListItems.length=0;                    
            //generate UI in groupListItems
            //if I change groupListItems to be [], callback's called but empty UI is not rendered
            dispatch(genGroupList(groups,groupListItems));
            return this.paintUI(groupListItems);}),()=>{}
      );
  //original flow; this flow can work normally; render of this flow is normal
  dispatch(genGroupList(groups,groupListItems));
  return this.paintUI(groupListItems);

}
```

Since I encountered a situation that react asked me to anyway put return in the  bottom of render, I can't help wonder if any render in the callback is not legal in react?

I really need to render in the callback of the unblocking IO; any ideas are welcome.

Comment: You've given us not a lot to work with since we don't know what any of those functions do, but the basics are that you'll want to do your async stuff in the componentDidMount lifecycle hook, and when its done call `this.setState`. Render should be a pure function of state and props.

Comment: React components will call the render method whenever their props change, or `this.setState` is called. So you can move the asynchronous bit outside of the render method, and do one of these two things in its callback or resolution.

Answer (score 0):

From the context available within the question, My answer will be:

- Almost always, you don't want to be doing any async operation within the `render` method.
- React provides a set of lifecycle methods to solve for this. In your case, depending on when you want the async method to be actioned, you will use the following:

  1. `ComponentDidMount` (If you want your method to be actioned as soon as React loads respective component)
  2. Specify rules for update within `ShouldComponentUpdate` and execute your async function in `ComponentDidUpdate`; if you have "LIVE" data that needs processing via an Async method.

Inside your Async function, use `this.setState({key: value})` pattern to set the results of an async function to state. In your `render` method, you should be using the respective state variable. This is ideally, healthy way of coding in React.